# Prove the complex conjugate

Tags: complex-numbers

If $w$ and $z$ are two complex number, prove that  $$\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^* = \frac{w^*}{z^*}$$
My attempt:$$\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^* = \left(w \cdot \frac{1}{z}\right)^*$$
$$\left(w \cdot \frac{1}{z}\right)^* = w^* \cdot \left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^*$$
Hence, $$\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^* = \frac{w^*}{z^*}$$

Comment: If to you $\frac1{z^*}=\left(\frac1z\right)^*$ is a given, then you're done.

Comment: I'd say write them in polar form and it'd be neater, but like Dumper said if the complex conjugate of an inverse is the inverse of the conjugate then this is fine

Comment: It depends what you are supposed to know, i.e. how $*$ was defined to you. Was it only in cartesian coordinates? or polar as well?

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo Or just use the formulas for real and imaginary part, because the sooner you learn them by heart the better.

Comment: @DumperDGarb   I suggested polar form because the division in standard real and imaginary part may be less straightforward to apply the definition of the conjugate

Comment: @LourencoEntrudo Very arguably, but that was what "the sooner the better" stood for.

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* We can consider real and imaginary part of $w$ and $z$ in the form
\begin{align*}
w&=a+ib\qquad\qquad a,b\in\mathbb{R}\\
z&=c+id\qquad\qquad c,d\in\mathbb{R}
\end{align*}

> We obtain by consequently splitting the complex number into real and imaginary part
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\left(\frac{w}{z}\right)^{*}}&=\left(\frac{a+ib}{c+id}\right)^{*}\\
> &=\left(\frac{(a+ib)(c-id)}{c^2+d^2}\right)^{*}\\
> &=\left(\frac{ac+bd}{c^2+d^2}-i\frac{ad-bc}{c^2+d^2}\right)^{*}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{ac+bd}{c^2+d^2}+i\frac{ad-bc}{c^2+d^2}}
> \end{align*}
> On the other hand we get
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\frac{w^{*}}{z^{*}}}&=\frac{a-ib}{c-id}=\cdots
> \end{align*}

Can you continue?

Comment: There's a small typo in the second equation from the top: "$z = c + i\mathbf{b}$" should be "$z = c + i\mathbf{d}$"

Comment: @KevinDietrich: Many thanks. Typo corrected.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is as follows: Let $w=ae^{i\alpha}$ and $z=be^{i\beta}$. Then

$$\bigg(\frac{w}{z}\bigg)=\frac{a}{b}e^{i(\alpha-\beta)}$$

So,

$$\bigg(\frac{w}{z}\bigg)^*=\frac{a}{b}e^{-i(\alpha-\beta)}=\frac{ae^{-i\alpha}}{be^{-i\beta}}=\frac{w^*}{z^*}$$

Obviously, this is general and applicable to any values of the parameters.